# Determining Conditions on Singular Values

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n\times p$ matrix. What are the conditions on the singular values of $A$ for there to exist a $p\times p$ matrix $B$ such that $BA^T$ is a matrix with orthonormal columns.

We know: 
$BA^T = B(ULV^T)^T = BVL^TU^T$. Does this suggest that the singular values do not change? If so, are the necessary conditions for an orthogonal matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Let's use a slightly different notation.

$ A = U_L \Sigma_{TL} V_L^T $ be the reduced Singular Value Decomposition where $ \Sigma_{TL} $ is $ r \times r $, diagonal, and has positive elements on the diagonal.

Let $ X = B A^T $.  This means we want to know when there exists a matrix $ B $ such that $ X^T X = I $.

Thus, $ B $ must make it so that 
$ I = X^T X = V_L \Sigma_{TL} U_L^T B^T B U_L \Sigma_{TL} V_L^T $.

Now, multiply from the left by $ V_L^T $ and the right by $ V_L^T $.
Then
$ I = \Sigma_{TL} U_L^T B^T B U_L \Sigma_{TL} $.

Now, if you pick $ B = ... $.

But now you want $ B $ to be $ p \times p $...  Under what condition is $ ... $ square?

You fill in the details!